# How do I install OpenShift Origin through Vagrant and VirtualBox?

Tags: vagrant, openshift, virtualbox, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to install OpenShift Origin All-in-one on my MacBook Pro, and I am struggling. I have tried following various tutorials, but (in my opinion) every source and every step involved with the process is fragmented because it's open source... forgive me if I am rude towards the open source community, I am just frustrated with the amount of effort this seemingly "quick" solution requires.

To install OpenShift Origin All-in-one, I need to install Vagrant and VirtualBox. I don't know if I have properly installed Vagrant or VirtualBox because there are dozens of tutorials telling me various different start up commands. Some tutorials start by presuming you have Vagrant installed, some tutorials start by telling you to execute $ vagrant init, some tutorials start by telling you to execute $ vagrant up, etc etc. It seems there is no definitive answer. Furthermore, it seems that the tutorials were created a few years ago and are not relevant for the recent updates.

Therefore, does anyone have any end-to-end complete tutorials they could share with me? Or does anyone have any advice on how I can install OpenShift Origin All-in-one without missing steps relating to the installation of Vagrant and the appropriate boxes etc?

I have tried reading the free OpenShift for Developers e-book, but again, the author misses out/presumes you've installed steps 1-5. It seems everyone is more than willing to share how to download OpenShift Origin All-in-one without actually sharing how to download the relevant tools, executing the correct commands and in the appropriate order. If it worked on their machine, on their version, on their date then it's the correct method, however, it seemingly changes frequently.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Part of the reason installing VirtualBox/Vagrant is not gone through in detail is that it differs on each platform and can also change over time as those products change how they do things. The web sites for those products should provide adequate information. Use the product web sites in preference to third party tutorials which can be out of date. Another option is to sign up for the OpenShift Online developer preview. Then you don't need to go through the steps to install OpenShift on your own computer. https://www.openshift.com/devpreview/

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift has now support for painless `oc cluster up`. Only docker is required. For more info see: https://install.openshift.com